# Parsing html with phpQuery : how to handle C++ code inside a pre tag?

Tags: php, html, parsing, pre, phpquery

In the database I have some code like this one

```
Some text
<pre>
#include <cstdio> 

int x = 1;
</pre>
Some text
```

When I'm trying to use phpQuery to do the parsing it fails because the `<cstdio>` is interpreted as a tag.

I could use `htmlspecialchars` but to apply it only inside `pre` tags I still need to do some parsing. I could use regex but it will be much more difficult (I will need to handle the possible attributes of the `pre` tag) and the idea of using a parser was to avoid this kind of regex thing.

What's the best way to do what I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went the regex way, considering only simple attributes for the `pre` tag (no '>' inside the attributes) :

```
  foreach(array('pre', 'code') as $sTag)
     $s = preg_replace_callback("#\<($sTag)([^\>]*?)\>(.+?)\<\/$sTag\>#si",
     function($matches)
     {
        $matches[3] = str_replace(array('&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), array('&', '<', '>'), $matches[3]);      
        return "<{$matches[1]} {$matches[2]}>".htmlentities($matches[3], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")."</{$matches[1]}>";
     },
     $s);
```

It also deals with caracters being already converted to html entities (we don't want to have it twice).

Not a perfect solution but given the data I need to apply it on it will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to do encode HTML (& > and so on) before assembly

Comment: Yes I know but the editing is done by the users and I can't ask them to do it. To do it automatically I need to find a way to encode the caracters only inside `pre` tags. Can I do that without having to build a complex regex ? That's my question.

Comment: Okay - i did not know that. Javascript has this buildin feature. You must be able to get content after user but before server ? var clean = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('[your stuff]').textValue);

Comment: If javascript can do it, php can also do it. The problem is to correctly identify and encode ONLY the content inside `pre` tags even if the tags have weird (but valid) attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The error is, that your database contains `HTML` that contains some text which is not correctly encoded already.

So, if you want to save time and have a correct solution, then you should make sure, that the HTML in your database is correctly encoded. This means, you should make sure that everything will be correctely encoded (using `htmlspecialchars()`) **before it is saved to your database**!

Otherwise you just save garbage in your database, and you will have to write some special code to "prettify that garbage".

Any other solutions are workarounds, and those will cost you precious time in your future.

So: the best solution is to make sure, that anything you write to your database is correct.

Comment: Yes, indeed. However the content in the database is already big so I'll need to sanitize it (and we're back to the same problem). Also since user need to edit these texts, I can't ask them to use `&gt;` or to have to see them while editing...